# Add a class to every third wordpress post

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

Im listing all wordpress posts in the blog category but trying to add a class called 'last' to every third 'fourcol' class

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

    <?php query_posts('category_name=blog&showposts=10&orderby=date&order=dsc'); if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <div class="fourcol">
            <a href=""><h2 class="blogtitle"><?php the_title(); ?></h2></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="images/_scroll1.jpg"></a>
            <span class="date">12 May 2011</span>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            <a class="more" href="#">Keep reading</a>
                </div><!-- fourcol END -->

            <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
        </div><!-- row END -->
    </div><!-- container END -->
```

Hope this makes sense?

Comment: Updated my answer for you. Misread it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using CSS

Instead of

```
.last
```

Use

```
.fourcol:nth-child(3n+1)
```

Comment: This works well but would ideally like to set it as a sequence, ie: the class 'last' would be applied to posts 3,6,9,12 etc

Comment: What about internet explorer?

Comment: Which version of IE are you talking about ?

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:**

```
var i = 1;
$('#row .fourcol').each(function() {
    if(i++ % 4 == 0) 
        $(this).addClass('last'); 
});
```

---

```
$('.fourcol').eq(3).addClass('last');
```

Comment: you beat me to it. +1
there wont be an easier way than that

Comment: Why would you use javascript to do this?

Comment: @locrizak: look at this questions tags.

Comment: I realize that but hes looking for advice and javascript is not the way to do it

Comment: No, he's trying to "Add a class to every third wordpress post". My solution does just that.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php query_posts('category_name=blog&showposts=10&orderby=date&order=dsc'); 
if ( have_posts() ) : 
    $i=0;
    while ( have_posts() ) : 
        the_post(); 
    ++$i; 
    ?>

    <div class="fourcol<?php if($i%3==0) echo ' every-third-post' ?>" >
        <a href=""><h2 class="blogtitle"><?php the_title(); ?></h2></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/_scroll1.jpg"></a>
        <span class="date">12 May 2011</span>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <a class="more" href="#">Keep reading</a>
            </div><!-- fourcol END -->

        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
    </div><!-- row END -->
</div><!-- container END -->
```

Try this. Should work.

Answer (score 2):

you need the [modulus operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php)

```
<?php query_posts('category_name=blog&showposts=10&orderby=date&order=dsc'); 
    $counter = 0; //add a ounter to keep track of the number post we're on
    if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    //check if the remainder of $count is 0, if so add the class 'last'
    <div class="fourcol <? if ( $count % 3 == 0 ) echo 'last' ?>">                                                        
        <a href=""><h2 class="blogtitle"><?php the_title(); ?></h2></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/_scroll1.jpg"></a>
        <span class="date">12 May 2011</span>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <a class="more" href="#">Keep reading</a>
    </div><!-- fourcol END -->
    <? $count++; ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Comment: Great this works but adds the class to the first post and not the third, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with PHP in your template.  Just add the string `last` on every third post. The following variant makes use of the [existing post counter in wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Properties) and the [modulo operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php). The counter starts at 0 so we add 1 to it every time:

```
<div class="fourcol<?php if ( !((1 + $wp_query->current_post) % 3) ) echo ' last' ?>">
```

This is fairly compact and the most compact solution I can imagine for wordpress on the PHP side of your theme.

The idea behind it is the following:

Add a variable as a counter, count it up on every post and if it is 3, set it to 0 again and add the class.

The following script shows each of this step: Define the counter if it does not exists, count it up, reset it to 0 if applicable and do the echo:

```
<div class="fourcol<?php

  isset($iposts) || $iposts = 0;

  if (++$iposts === 3)
  {
    $iposts = 0;

    echo ' last';
  }

 ?>">
```

That's for demonstration only. As you're using the standard query object, it's much more easy as we can re-use an existing variable. Additionally making use of the [modulo operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) helps to find every X element.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( have_posts() ) : while( have_posts() ) : the_post();
//Loop code goes here. 
if ( 0 == $count%4 ) {
    echo 'div class="clrFix"></div>';
}
endwhile; 
if ( 0 != $count%4 ) {
   echo 'div class="clrFix"></div>';
```

}

Here add a clrFix div after every 4 post.